# Version of google packages in Android

Tags: android, gradle

I find my self struggling with the package version numbers for different google libraries in and Android project.

Is there a easy way to see a list of released version numbers for `com.google.android.gms:play-services` or `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`?

Edit:

For example I have:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+'`

I know there is a `5.2.+` version because my ide suggested I update but is there a 5.1 version? How can I find out?

Comment: Try this, "https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html" if you have already check this link excuse me.

Comment: Thank you @Sid I've added a edit for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look directly at the repositories on disk. For Play Services, look in the Google repository. From your SDK's root directory:

> extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/

For appcompat, look in the Android repository:

> extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/

Comment: right on man, I've been browsing that extras folder for wile now had a hunch that they are hidden deep in there somewhere